# Stripe Invoice not creating after upcoming invoice

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments

I am working with Stripe Laravel php billing system.

I created a client with a subscription and a trial period.
An invoice with 0 amount is getting created. Once the trial period is completed I can see an upcoming invoice and I can preview this invoice.

Below is what I see in stripe..

```
Upcoming invoice for $67.50 Preview
Next invoice for subscription to Pro|Will be billed on Mar 19
```

[image]

Problem is invoice is not getting created once the trial period is over and upcoming invoice stays upcoming today is Mar21 and you it is the same status..

What am I doing wrong here.

Below my laravel code to create the subscription in question with a coupon code and trial period.

```
//create subscription with calculated trial period
                $subscription = $stripeObj->subscriptions->create([
                    'coupon' => $this->stripe_discount_coupons["$discount_percent"],
                    'customer' => $firmData->stripe_id,
                    'items' => [
                        [
                            'price' => $firmData->commitment->stripe_price_id,
                            'quantity'=> $firmData->number_of_users
                        ],
                    ],
                    'cancel_at_period_end'=> false,
                    'metadata'=>[
                        'firm_id'=>$firmData->id,
                        'firm_name'=>$firmData->firm_name,
                        'subscription_name'=>$firmData->subscription->subscription_type,
                    ],
                    'expand' => ['latest_invoice.payment_intent'],
                    'trial_end' => $final_trial_period
                ]);
```

I have also tried.. logging into stripe dashboard and opened the customer subscription and edited it without making any changes, and I can see the upcoming invoice is not converted into invoice..

Not sure whats happening above. I have created almost 20 clients with various trial periods ranging from 10 min to 1 day. The result is the same, all I see is an upcoming invoice.

Comment: Really hard to say -- overall the code looks okay. I'd recommend writing into Stripe Support with a specific Subscription ID, or reaching out via their Discord server (https://discord.com/invite/stripe) to get help with the specific example you are testing.

Comment: I have dropped an email with them and awaiting their reply. I wanted to share the situation with the community for a discussion at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues here that need to be addressed wrt my situation..

one- Regular events like CustomerSubscriptionTrialWillEnd will not fire if trial period duration is less than 3 days.

two - we need to provide what is the default behavior once the trial ends.

The updated code that works for me is provided below.. I am using a coupon to provide a discount and also using a trial period. You can see in the trial_settings i am proving an end_behavior which instructs to create_invoice once the trial is expired.

```
$subscription = $stripeObj->subscriptions->create([
                'coupon' => $this->stripe_discount_coupons["$discount_percent"],
                'customer' => $firmData->stripe_id,
                'items' => [
                    [
                        'price' => $firmData->commitment->stripe_price_id,
                        'quantity'=> $firmData->number_of_users
                    ],
                ],
                'cancel_at_period_end'=> false,
                'metadata'=>[
                    'firm_id'=>$firmData->id,
                    'firm_name'=>$firmData->firm_name,
                    'subscription_name'=>$firmData->subscription->subscription_type,
                ],
                'expand' => ['latest_invoice.payment_intent'],
                'trial_end' => $final_trial_period,
                'trial_settings' => ['end_behavior' => ['missing_payment_method' => 'create_invoice']],
            ]);
```